# Why is document.getElementsByClassName constantly returning an undefined array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a simple Chrome extension that activates YouTube Dark Mode by clicking a couple buttons.

```
alert("Clicker");

//document.getElementsByClassName("button.style-scope.ytd-topbar-menu-button-renderer")[0].click();
var buttons = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("button.style-scope.ytd-topbar-menu-button-renderer").innerHTML);

console.log(buttons[0]);
buttons[0].click();
```

I'm testing this on https://www.youtube.com/feed/trending. I have a manifest.json of:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Youtube Dark Mode",
    "version": "1.0.0",

    "permissions": [
        "https://www.youtube.com/*",
        "tabs",
        "activeTab"
    ],

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Engage Youtube Dark Mode."
    },

    "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.youtube.com/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }]
}
```

And a background.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    //alert("Boat");

    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "clicker.js"});
});
```

I've read a lot of similar posts on here, but none of their suggestions have worked for me (probably because I don't know Javascript well). The problem is that either `.click` is not a property of `buttons[0]` or the `buttons` array is undefined.

This code is essentially trying to put `$("button.ytd-topbar-menu-button-renderer").click();` into extension form, since I know that that jQuery works in the developer console.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Because `.innerHTML` on a collection of elements does return undefined? Drop that property access!

Comment: this doesn't look like a className: `'button.style-scope.ytd-topbar-menu-button-renderer'`. Change to: `'style-scope ytd-topbar-menu-button-renderer'` or use `querySelectorAll` instead!

Comment: It turns out both of these comments together do the trick (See the Accepted Answer). Thanks @bergi and ibrahim-mahrir !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `.` in className for `document.getElementsByClassName`

if you want to select with the selector `"button.style-scope.ytd-topbar-menu-button-renderer"` use `document.querySelectorAll` instead.

Comment: Oh that totally worked. I also had to remove the .innerHTML too: 
`var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button.ytd-topbar-menu-button-renderer")[0];

console.log(buttons);
buttons.click();`

Comment: Thanks for the help!